# Do you know how to bind one-many association to Golang struct without orm?

Tags: sql, go

Do you know how to bind a one-to-many association to a Golang struct without using an ORM?

I want to bind the SQL results below to the following Golang struct:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
    users (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255)
    );

CREATE TABLE
    posts (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("one"), ("two");

INSERT INTO
    posts (user_id, title)
VALUES (1, "one's post"), (1, "one's second post"), (1, "one's third post"), (2, "two's post"), (2, "two's second post"), (2, "two's third post");

SELECT u.id, u.name, p.id, p.title
FROM users AS u
JOIN posts AS p ON u.id = p.user_id;
```

```golang
type (
  User struct {
    ID int
    Name string
    Posts []*Post
  }

  Post struct {
    ID int
    Title string
  }
)
```

I often use MySQL. So I want the method with MySQL. But if you know good method with PostgreSQL, MariaDb and so on, please teach me that method.

Answer (score 2):

```golang
func example() ([]*User, error) {
    // execute select query
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT ...`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // use a map for easy lookup of already scanned users
    userMap := make(map[int]*User)

    // iterate over the returned rows
    for rows.Next() {
        // declare a variable for each column returned by the query
        var (
            uid   int
            uname string
            // Use sql.NullXxx types since your JOIN
            // can potentially result in rows with NULLs,
            // or use COALESCE in your query, then you won't
            // have to use these types.
            pid    sql.NullInt64
            ptitle sql.NullString
        )

        // scan the current row's columns into the variables
        if err := rows.Scan(&uid, &uname, &pid, &ptitle); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // lookup the user in the map using the scanned id
        u, ok := userMap[uid]
        if !ok {
            // if not found, create a new instance of the user and store it in the map
            u = &User{ID: uid, Name: uname}
            userMap[uid] = u
        }

        // add the post instance to the user
        u.Posts = append(u.Posts, &Post{
            ID:    int(pid.Int64),
            Title: ptitle.String,
        })
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // convert map into slice
    users := make([]*User, 0, len(userMap))
    for _, u := range userMap {
        users = append(users, u)
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind a **one-to-many** association to a **Golang** struct without an **ORM**, you can use the **MySQL** driver for **Golang** to execute a query that fetches the required data from the database and then manually map the result to the struct.

I will give  you  an example of how you can achieve this using the **MySQL** driver:

```
/* *  @Author: Sk Shahriar Ahmed Raka   * Email: skshahriarahmedraka@gmail.com   * @Last Modified by:   Sk Shahirar Ahmed Raka  * @Last Modified time: 2023-04-23 00:16:31  */


package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type User struct {
    ID    int
    Name  string
    Posts []*Post
}

type Post struct {
    ID    int
    Title string
}

func main() {
    // Connect to the mysql database
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/databasename")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" sql.Open() ~ err : ", err)

    }
    defer db.Close()
    // Prepare the SQL query in a string format
    query := `SELECT u.id, u.name, p.id, p.title FROM Users AS u JOIN posts AS p ON u.id = p.user_id `
    // Execute your  query string
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" db.Query(query)~ err : ", err)

    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // you have to map the results to the struct
    Users := []*User{}
    var userMap = make(map[int]*User)
    for rows.Next() {
        userID:=0
        userName:=""
        postID:=0
        postTitle:=""

        err := rows.Scan(&userID, &userName, &postID, &postTitle)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(" rows.Scan() ~ err : ", err)

        }

        user, ok := userMap[userID]
        if !ok {
            user = &User{ID: userID, Name: userName, Posts: make([]*Post, 0)}
            userMap[userID] = user
            Users = append(Users, user)
        }

        user.Posts = append(user.Posts, &Post{ID: postID, Title: postTitle})
    }
    // Print your results
    for _, user := range Users {
        fmt.Printf("UserID: %d, Name: %s\n", user.ID, user.Name)
        for _, post := range user.Posts {
            fmt.Printf("    PostID: %d, Title: %s\n", post.ID, post.Title)
        }
    }
}
```

For this example, first you need to connect to the **MySQL** database using the `sql.Open` function from the `database/sql` package and prepare the **SQL query** to fetch the required data. You then execute the query using the `db.Query` function and loop over the resulting rows to map the data to the `User` and `Post` structs manually.To map the results to the structs, you first create a **map** to store the `User` structs based on their ID, and then loop over the rows to create or update the `User` structs and their associated `Post` structs. you print the results by looping over the `User` structs and their associated `Post` structs.